# ubuntu 13.10 terminal access error

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, desktop

When I try to access my ubuntus 13.10 terminal I get `bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long`. And I can't figure out what the problem means. I can't use of sudo su everything hangs

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a misconfigured package. I was going to add this as a comment, but since you state you do not have sudo, it is slightly more complex. Turn your pc off, insert the installation medium (usb, cd), and boot from this, not from your hard disk. Choose the option "Try Ubuntu without installing it". Open a terminal, mount your hdd. You can locate your disk partition with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Assuming your system is on /dev/sda1,

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo chroout /mnt
sudo apt-get --reinstall install core-utils
exit
```

Now turn off your pc, and restart it without the installation medium (usb, cd). This assumes that only the core-utils package was defective. If at this point your problem is not solved, you are probably better off by redoing the installation. Only, nect time you download an iso, perform a checksum on the iso you downloaded, it will save you many later headaches.

If by any chance, you upgraded by means of do-dist-upgrade, since you do not have an iso it is impossible to perform the check I just mentioned (and many other things, which shows you why I never upgrade via do-dist-upgrade, I only had bad experiences with it). In this case, my suggestion is still to download an iso image, and upgrade from there.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. It seems like the only option is what you adviced because everything is down

Comment: I have been trying but did not work. I do not want to reinstall the hole stuff I have a lot data is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your /home on a different partition than /?

Comment: mainly the var directory all my web stuffs

Comment: But is it on the same partition as /, or on a different partition?

Comment: I have just one main partition. I know is a really big mistake but...

Answer (score 0):

Utility `dircolors` will use environment variable `LS_COLORS` if it exists, otherwise it would use some default value from resource database.

If your `LS_COLORS` is too long or otherwise corrupted, this would cause trouble. You can check it using printenv:

```
printenv LS_COLORS
```

or see how big it is with `wc -c`:

```
printenv LS_COLORS | wc -c
```

On my Ubuntu 13.10 machine it is 1304 bytes long, and it works just fine. 
It is possible that you have upgraded from older Ubuntu, and your `LS_COLORS` is set to some weird value in `~/.bashrc` or in some other startup script.